# Where can I get open career path related data of people from various professions?

Tags: data-request

Information that I need specifically from the career path is :
1. Bachelors university and Stream of study(Eg. B.E. in Computer Science from Stanford)
2. Masters University and Stream of study (Data points Similar as bachelors)
3. Doctoral University and Stream of study
4. Present company and post at which the person is working.

That's it. No name, nothing else.

Comment: For what country?

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul Preferably India or USA or any other country will do.

Comment: It's rare to find open datasets that have records like this for individual people and names of specific companies or organizations. But if you take away the specific university names and company names, you'll be able to find more statistics. Would that work?